# Why sometimes when generating a new grid i'm getting exception of missing renderer component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the exception message:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the
>   "Bottom Wall" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
>   probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "Bottom Wall". Or
>   your script needs to check if the component is attached before using
>   it.

I have 3 scripts attached to the same GameObject in the Hierarchy.

The first script generate a grid:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<GameObject> blocks = new List<GameObject>();

    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];

    void Start()
    {
        wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
        wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
        wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
        wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

        GenerateGrid();

        var testing = GetComponent<tester>();
        tester.Test();
    }

    public void AutoGenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.Count; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(blocks[i]);
        }
        GenerateGrid();
        var testing = GetComponent<tester>();
        tester.Test();
    }

    public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.tag = "Block";
                block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.1f, 1);
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);

                if (x == 0)//TOP
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[0].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "TopWall";
                    blocks.Add(block);
                }
                else if (z == 0)//LEFT
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[1].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "LeftWall";
                    blocks.Add(block);
                }
                else if (z == gridHeight - 1)//RIGHT
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[2].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "RightWall";
                    blocks.Add(block);
                }

                else if (x == gridWidth - 1)//BOTTOM
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[3].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "BottomWall";
                    blocks.Add(block);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second script pick randomly two objects from any two walls:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class tester : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];

    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
            wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
            wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
            wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

            var wallsList = wallsParents.ToList();

            // remove random 2 times
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                wallsList.Remove(wallsList[Random.Range(0, wallsList.Count)]);
            }

            var childsWall0 = wallsList[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            var childsWall1 = wallsList[1].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            var randomBlock = childsWall0[Random.Range(0, childsWall0.Length)];
            var randomBlock1 = childsWall1[Random.Range(0, childsWall1.Length)];

            randomBlock.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            randomBlock1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
        catch(MissingComponentException missing)
        {
            var mis = missing;
        }
    }
}
```

The third script add a button to the inspector and should generate each time a new grid with picked two random blocks from two random walls:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(GridGenerator))]
public class GenerateGridButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        GridGenerator myScript = (GridGenerator)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate New Grid"))
        {
            myScript.AutoGenerateGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i make some clicks on the button it's working fine but then after some clicks the exception is throw each time on another wall. Sometime on the Bottom Wall sometime on Left Right or Top. Sometimes after two clicks sometimes after 10 clicks on the button.

Before i added the button and the AutoGenerateGrid method it was working fine i was running the game and it was creating each time a new grid with two picked random walls and two picked blocks from the two walls.

After all when i click the button and destroying the all existing cubes and then create new cubes the new cubes should have renderer component.

I can't figure out what make this exception. i added try and catch but it didn't give me much more help.

I know the question is a bit long but each script is connected to each other so it's hard to narrow the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually doing what you mentioned to it.

```
var childsWall0 = wallsList[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
var childsWall1 = wallsList[1].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
var randomBlock = childsWall0[Random.Range(0, childsWall0.Length)];
var randomBlock1 = childsWall1[Random.Range(0, childsWall1.Length)];

randomBlock.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
randomBlock1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

If you read carefully this [thread](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) what is happening is you are getting the Transform component in your parent gameobject along with child game objects. Ofcourse if your parent game  object wont have any **Renderer** if you are using it as a holder for group of objects. So for that you will have to get all the child of the gameobject and not parent gameobject itself. 
And because you are doing Random with all objects tranform it will sometimes give the error if its parent was selected in the range. What I would suggest is romove the reference of parents in your childWall0 and childWall1 or another method is

```
 foreach (Transform child in transform) {
        //Add this child to your childsWall0 & childsWall1
 }
```

But this will work only with intermediate objects and not nested. If you have nested elements better use your method but just remove parent that should solve your problem.

Also here are reference thread for finding child [transfrom](https://forum.unity.com/threads/quickly-retrieving-the-immediate-children-of-a-gameobject.39451/)